# Mobaxterm is crashing on DNS ipv6 connection

Tags: ssh, dns, ipv6, mobaxterm

When I connect using ipv4 to my server, using DNS or not, or by ipv6 without DNS, the connection is done smoothly.

However, when I use DNS and ipv6, after the banner message, the Mobaxterm freezes and is not responding for several seconds before I get access to the shell.
However, when testing on Powershell, there is no special latency :

```
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------

Authorized access only!

If you are not authorized to access or use this system, disconnect now!

All actions will be logged and unauthorized access could be legally pursued!

------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Jean\\.ssh\\id_server
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\\Users\\Jean\\.ssh\\id_server':
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxxxxx.com ([2xxxx:xxxxxxxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/jean/.ssh/authorized_keys:4: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
Linux server 6.1.21-v7+ #1642 SMP Mon Apr  3 17:20:52 BST 2023
```

Comment: Does the DNS resolve to exactly the same address? Are you using any form of tunnel or VPN for your IPv6 access? (This sounds a bit like a PMTUD issue, although I can't think of why only DNS would have an effect on it.)

Comment: Try to disable temporarily the firewall.

Comment: Okay, I will try. Yes the DNS is directing to the machine but what is strange, I get the bug after the banner so the resolution seems okay and connection via Powershell does not cause any troubleshoots. I added the source IP to an accept rule on the firewall and still same issue.